# onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)‬ to 0-100 scale

Tags: android

When I use onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)‬ of RecognitionListener I get it in root min squere dB. I want to convert it to the scale of 0 to 100. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated a bit in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) and I used this:

```
10*Math.pow(10, ((double)volume/(double)10))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you went with this answer instead of the one posted by ohaleck?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO linear scale for sound volume is pretty useless.

As the rms value varies from -120 to 60, the best way to normalize it to the scale of 0-100 would be:

`float volumeNo = (volumeDB+120​)/1.8`

Comment: OK, I'll try and let you know